# nest multiple columns into an array in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Given this BQ Table
[image: BQ Table]
[image]

there are 1.026 rows with 944 unique modemio_cat_ids

how can I return a query that nests all non null columns into **1 single array** called "parents" for each modemio_cat_id ?

example: for modemio_cat_id = 1111118

[image: nested catx_id into parent]

and then finally group by modemio_cat_id + cumulate all array in case of duplicates

*wrong approach*: this query returns always the same arrays for each modemutti_cat_id:

```
SELECT modemio_cat_id, ARRAY (
  SELECT AS STRUCT cat1_id, cat2_id FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.categorization.test`
  ) as parent
FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.categorization.test` 
group by modemio_cat_id
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT modemio_cat_id, 
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT cat_id IGNORE NULLS) parents
FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.categorization.test`,
  UNNEST([cat1_id, cat2_id, cat3_id, cat4_id, cat5_id, cat6_id]) cat_id
GROUP BY modemio_cat_id
```